# Find Root Column Value in Chain

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a Sybase table which is structured as follows.  Assume the `id` column is in chronological order (oldest first).

```
|id |data|refId|
|---|----|-----|
|1  |d1  |NULL |
|2  |d2  |NULL |
|3  |d3  |NULL |
|4  |d4  |2    |
|5  |d5  |4    |
|6  |d6  |5    |
```

What SQL code can be used within a stored procedure to produce the following result:

```
|id |data|
|---|----|
|1  |d1  |
|2  |d6  |
|3  |d3  |
```

For example, id 2 was amended with new data 3 times.  First by row 4, then by row 5, and finally by row 6.

I need to always use the original id when publishing amendments.  So on the day when I need to publish the amended data in row 6 (d6), I need to find the original id (2) by chaining backwards using refId.

```
6-->5-->4-->2
```

Since ids 1 & 3 have no corresponding refId, the data for these rows is current.

Some additionally important stuff:

`Server: Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0 SP03 PL08`

`Driver URL: jdbc:jtds:sybase`

`Driver: Sybase jTDS`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in table `test`, following sp will loop through the hierarchy:

```
create procedure sp_hierarchical_loop
as
begin
declare @cont int

create table #test2 (
id int, 
data char(2), 
refId int null
)

insert into #test2
select id, data, id
from test
where refId is null

set @cont = 1

while (@cont>0) begin
  update #test2
   set t1.data=t2.data, t1.refId=t2.id
  from #test2 t1, test t2
  where isnull(t1.refId,t1.id)=t2.refId

  if (row_count()=0) set @cont=0
end 

select id, data 
from #test2

end
go
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit lengthy for a comment ...

First thing you need to do is determine which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQL Anywhere? Advantage?) and version you're using as these products don't share a common SQL syntax.

If you're using IQ or SQL Anywhere you can probably use a common table expression (CTE) utilizing the `WITH` or `WITH RECURSIVE` clause.  A few links on this topic: [blog re: recursive queries](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/02/04/using-recursive-queries-with-sql-anywhere/), [blog re: recursive union](https://sqlanywhere.blogspot.com/2012/04/example-recursive-union.html) and [bog re: recursive union tree traversal](https://sqlanywhere.blogspot.com/2012/10/example-recursive-union-tree-traversal.html).

If you're using ASE you're out of luck when it comes to CTEs (ie, these are not supported by ASE).  This leaves you with writing a procedural solution (eg, cursor based looping construct) as either a stored proc or if running a newer version of ASE (15.7, 16.x) possibly a user defined function (though even a UDF is going to require some sort of looping/recursive coding).

I'm not familiar with Advantage so can't make any suggestions here other than to look through the documentation (aka 'RTFM') and see if it supports recursive CTEs or a looping/recursive coding option.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the additional info.  I believe that ASE 16 does now support CTE but I can't seem to get it work in my JDBC client (DBeaver) but I am not experienced with CTE so I'm struggling with examples right now.  I may just abandoned the idea and post process the result set with a programming language like Python or Java to follow the chain of IDs.

Comment: @MichaelStarkie ASE 16 does *not* have support for CTEs, hence the reason you can't get it to work :-)